# Reset RealVnc Server Advanced Options On Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc

When connecting to Real Vnc Server running on Raspberry Pi 3B I mistakenly set the advanced option here to [directly render apps](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002249917-VNC-Connect-and-Raspberry-Pi#running-directly-rendered-apps-such-as-minecraft-remotely-0-5)

When I connect now (from various clients) I just get a black screen with the message "Cannot currently show the desktop" I also tried removing and re-creating the connection on the client devices and lowering the screen resolution etc but no dice there either.

To try and resolve this I removed and purged RealVnc Server via cli rebooted and re-installed it. This doesn't work however.

Does anyone know where the config files are to remove this rendering option? Had a good look online and in the file system but cant see anything obvious to help.

Thanks

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is given by the RealVNC people at -
https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/5060068870813

If you have enabled direct capture with the KMS driver enabled and need to disable it, you can do so at the command line by connecting to your Raspberry Pi using SSH and running the below commands:

`sudo sed -i '/CaptureTech/d' /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11`

`sudo vncserver-x11 -service -reload`

Comment: Please make sure you at least include a summary (anything important to answering the original question) in your answer. URLs tend to go dead, or change contents so they stop providing the information that's relevant here!

Comment: Thank you Harkant. This was the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

realvnc's settings for your user should be installed in `~/.vnc` in your user's `/home` directory.

system-wide settings can be configured in `/etc/vnc`

you could try a couple of things; manually check in `~/.vnc` folder and see if you can remove the specific problematic setting, or you could backup the config, then purge/delete your configs.

that should reset all of your settings.

Comment: Thanks I tried this. I purged Real Vnc Server, deleted the files that didn't delete manually through the cli, rebooted and re-installed the app and re-enabled the VNC service in the Pi configuration but unfortunately there was no change :(

Comment: interesting. You would think that would do it. i wouldn't think that the client-side would need to be purged, but I'm assuming you tried that too?  Not that this solves your problem with realvnc, but have you ever considered using NoMachine? https://www.nomachine.com/ I definitely prefer it myself.

Comment: Options set on the server override any options selected on the client machine. Also, vncserver options set in the UI are saved in a .vnc folder of the user account that runs the service. Default installation uses root, so /root/.vnc/config.d/ as specified by @harkant. I just ran into this issue myself and this helped me find the solution.